# In PHP, mirror one dynamic webpage?

Tags: php, dynamic, mirror

I have my blog at location /blog, and the content is dynamic.

I would like /index.php on my site to mirror /blog

How do I write index.php to mirror a dynamic webpage?

Comment: Can't you just write a redirect? It's going to be better than duplicate content (from the search engines' point of view) when it's indexed.

Comment: Why don't you make a redirection from index.php to /blog?  You can use header("Location: http://domain/blog"); in index.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should really just forward it or you'll get dinged for duplicate content by search engines. This should matter to you if you're interested in people finding your content via search.

index.php should have the following code:

```
<?php
    header('Location: /blog', true, 301);
    exit;
?>
```

Comment: Or use an iFrame, but again dupe content :/

Comment: Is a single duplicate homepage so bad from an SEO perspective? I can understand if you are duplicating content left and right, but this is literally one page.

Comment: Yeah, but it's your homepage. Think about it.